# What is the #{} syntax in Vim?

Tags: vimscript, dictionary

I just noticed this in a Vim help page:

```
popup_beval(s:balloonText, #{mousemoved: 'word'})
```

What is the `#{mousemoved: 'word'}`? It looks like a dict?

I tried using `:help #{`, but that doesn't show any results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as a "literal dict", and is just the same as a regular dictionary, except that you don't need to quote the keys with quotes: It's documented at [`:help literal-Dict`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#literal-Dict)

So `#{hello: 'x'}` is just a slightly more convenient way of writing `{'hello': 'x'}`:

```
:echo #{hello: 'x'} == {'hello': 'x'}
1
```

This was added in Vim 8.1.1705 (July 2019) and as of the time of writing (August 2019) this is *not* in Neovim yet.

Comment: Wonder why they didn't choose to use `#{` or `#{}` as a help tag.

Comment: I suggested this (ages ago), and `#{}` is now a help tag @BLayer

Comment: That's great! Thanks.